# Problema al llamar los datos con json

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo el siguiente problema estoy trabajando con table layout al ingresar la marca del vehículo los muestra muy bien, pero al ingresar el N° de filas que es el ID no lo muestra en las cajas de texto, este es el código que utilizo.

```
public void buscar(View view){
    cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message3).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desar buscar por Marca?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tbldatos.removeAllViews();
            tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
            tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
            String url = "http://192.168.1.90/oficina/buscar_vehiculos1.php?Marca_Vehiculo=" + et_busqueda.getText().toString();
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
                    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
                    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
                    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                            View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla, null, false);
                            colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                            colTipo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colTipo);
                            colMarca = registro.findViewById(R.id.colMarca);
                            colModelo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colModelo);
                            colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                            colTipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                            colMarca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                            colModelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                            tbldatos.addView(registro);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.90/oficina/buscar_vehiculos2.php?N_Filas="+et_busqueda.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response.length() == 1){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.get(0).toString());
                            et_filas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                            et_tipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                            et_marca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                            et_modelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                            et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Frmmarca.this, "Este registro no ha sido ingresado aún", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        et_busqueda.setText("");
                        et_busqueda.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Oficina");
    alert.show();
}
```

anteriormente verifique el código en php con postmann y este funciona bien, y no se en dónde está el error, creo que puede ser el error en el llamado de los datos que realizo a través del json, o en el llamado de datos, lo otro realizar un ciclo for para el llamado de los datos cuando el usuario ingrese el N° de Fila, se em olvidaba mencionar que utilizo mysql para el motor de la base de datos, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa. ¿Dónde es el problema exactamente? ¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados? Observa la parte del `onResponse` y verifica lo que recibes ahí o si entra en `onErrorResponse` depura el mensaje de error y dinos cuál es, de lo contrario, hay que intentar adivinar el problema. Puedes depurar poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código. Es una técnica muy fácil y extremadamente útil, que deberías poner en práctica. Te vas a ahorrar muuuuchas horas y muchos rompederos de cabeza tratando de encontrar problemas.

Comment: agrega lo que obtienes en response. Aporta más información revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu comentario y tu ayuda, te menciono que solucione el problema, hice lo siguiente cambie el código por un ciclo for y cambie el código de búsqueda en php y funciona muy bien y no hay problema ahora.

Comment: @Jorgesys muchas gracias por tu comentario y ayuda, como lo mencione anteriormente ya lo solucione, ahora lo que se me olvido consultar si puedo agregar la respuesta, ya que anteriormente lo hice alguien me menciono en los comentarios que no se debe hacer, pero sería bueno hacerlo para que alguien pase por lo mismo que yo, y que soy nuevo en estas lides y ayudar a alguien más

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Y es perfectamente válido responder a tu propia pregunta, claro está, explicando cuál ha sido la solución y poniendo el código que funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias